# How to configure CUPS to reject bad print jobs (<5k)?

Tags: printing, restrict, cups

I have an application team that doesn't know how to prevent their application from sending empty print jobs to the queue.  This is happening randomly, but at least once a minute.

Is there a way I can configure CUPS to reject empty print jobs, or print jobs that are below, say 5k?  All of the bad jobs are 3k which look like header info like time, date, sender, name of file and so on.  Just no content.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not possible with standard tools or settings provided by CUPS itself to require a minimum print jobfile size.
2. Only the *contrary*, setting the maximum print jobfile size is available This is controlled by making use of a `LimitRequestBody` setting in the *cupsd.conf* configuration file. By default, CUPS silently uses `LimitRequestBody 0`, which allows unlimited jobfile sizes.
3. To achieve what you want is easily possible via various methods. Each of these however would require some "hacking", writing your own filters for CUPS. (CUPS filters can be written in any language, even Bash/Shell.)
4. Since not enough details are available about your specific setup, it is not possible to suggest which of the many options would be best for your situation and to specify any details about it. It would be best if you hired somebody with enough CUPS expertise to advise you. I guess it can be done in a job of only a few hours....